# Difference between fields of tail and head sub-lists of the list: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `RDD[(String,Map[String,List[Product with Serializable]])]`, such as:

```
(1566,Map(data1 -> List(List(1469785000, 111, 1, 3, null, 0),List(1469785022, 111, 1, 3, null, 0)), data2 -> List((4,88,1469775603,1,3370,f,537490800,661.09)))
```

I want to create a new RDD that will contain the time difference beween tail and head sub-lists of the list of `data1` (converted to minutes).

For example, in the data sample above this refers to `1469785022` - `1469785000`.

I wrote the following code, but it fails with the error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`. It seems that `tail` and `head` do not work as expected. How to solve this issue?

```
  val newRDD = currentRDD.map({
    line => Map(("id",line._1),
                ("duration", (line._2.get("data1").get.tail.productElement(0).toString.toLong -                                        
                              line._2.get("data1").get.head.productElement(0).toString.toLong) / 60)
               )
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem of understanding of what is a `head` and what is a `tail`.

A `List()` object in Scala has a head and a tail. If you have a list like this:

```
scala> val list = List(10, 20, 30)
```

The structure of head and tail will be like this:

```
scala> list.head
res0: Int = 10
scala> list.tail
res1: List[Int] = List(20, 30)
```

So in your code when you use `tail` you are taking a `List[Int]` object. You can solve using `tail.head` like this:

```
line._2.get("data1").get.tail.head.productElement(0).toString.toLong
```

Comment: So, `tail` refers to the 1st element in the list, while `head` is the rest of elements, excluding the 1st one?

Comment: No. The oposite of this. `head` is the first element of a List. `tail` is the rest exclude the first. But the rest is a `List()`

Comment: So in order to calculate the difference between timestamps of the last and first sub-lists, I should apply something like this? : `line._2.get("data1").get.tail.head.productElement(0).toString.toLong - `line._2.get("data1").get.head.productElement(0).toString.toLong`

Comment: Yes! You need to do that.

Comment: Won't `tail.head` get the 2nd element, but not the last one? Imagine that I have 5 sub-lists in the list, not 2 as in my example.

Comment: You just have two elements. This case you will get the seccond. But if you are trying to get the last element of a list try this: `List(1, 2, 3).last`. But this is not fast for Long Lists.

Comment: Just to confirm. Let's say I have this data with 3 sublists `List(List(111,2,3),List(222,4,5),List(333,5,6))`. I want to subtract `111` from `333`: `line._2.get("data1").get.tail.last.productElement(0).toStrin‌​g.toLong - line._2.get("data1").get.head.productElement(0).toString.toL‌​ong`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The last you can use without tail. Use only last. And NoSuchElementException it is hard to say now...